# How would one generate a MAC address in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I need to generate a random MAC address for a project of mine, and I can not get it to work. Below is my current code (that is not working).

```
function genMAC(){
// Make a new array with all available HEX options.
var colours = new Array("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","A","B","C","D","E","F");
// Make variable to hold 6 character HEX array
partA = new Array(1);
partB = new Array(1);
partC = new Array(1);
partD = new Array(1);
partE = new Array(1);
partF = new Array(1);
mac-address="";
for (i=0;i<2;i++){
    // Loop for partA
    partA[i]=colours[Math.round(Math.random()*14)];
}
    for (i=0;i<2;i++){
    // Loop through 6 times, randomising the letter added to the array
    partB[i]=colours[Math.round(Math.random()*14)];
}
    for (i=0;i<2;i++){
    // Loop through 6 times, randomising the letter added to the array
    partC[i]=colours[Math.round(Math.random()*14)];
}
    for (i=0;i<2;i++){
    // Loop through 6 times, randomising the letter added to the array
    partD[i]=colours[Math.round(Math.random()*14)];
}
    for (i=0;i<2;i++){
    // Loop through 6 times, randomising the letter added to the array
    partE[i]=colours[Math.round(Math.random()*14)];
}
    for (i=0;i<2;i++){
    // Loop through 6 times, randomising the letter added to the array
    partF[i]=colours[Math.round(Math.random()*14)];
}
// Returns like "a10bc5". It is likely that you may need to add a "#".
mac-address = partA + ":" + partB + ":" + partC + ":" + partD + ":" + partE + ":" + partF;
return mac-address;
```

}

Ugly. I'm fairly new to JS and I am wondering if there is an easier way to do this that would work.

Comment: There need not be any checking on the MAC address. Basically, all I want is a randomly generated hex string in the form `XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX`

Comment: Math.random().toString(16) is a start...

Comment: @dandavis: …continued to `("0"+Math.floor(Math.random()*256).toString(16)).slice(-2)` :-)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
"XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX".replace(/X/g, function() {
  return "0123456789ABCDEF".charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * 16))
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/qhbC9/

Answer (score 13):

Here is a bit more of a "clean" version of your code, which takes the number of loops down to one. On each iteration of the loop, it appends two random characters to the `macAddress` variable, and if it's not the last iteration, it also appends a colon. Then it returns the generated address.

```
function genMAC(){
    var hexDigits = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    var macAddress = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        macAddress+=hexDigits.charAt(Math.round(Math.random() * 15));
        macAddress+=hexDigits.charAt(Math.round(Math.random() * 15));
        if (i != 5) macAddress += ":";
    }

    return macAddress;
}
```

Aside from being more complicated than necessary, there were two problems with your code. The first was that `mac-address` is an invalid variable name due to the dash. That caused the code to not work at all. With that fixed, the other problem was that when setting the MAC address variable at the end, you appended arrays to a string. That caused each of the arrays containing two hex digits to be converted to a string, which meant a comma was put between the two digits.

Comment: I really do need to pick up a book on JS. Also, it is not changing each use in the program. That might be a bug in my code though. Yep. it is. I'll fix it later.

Comment: It almost certainly is a bug in your code. See, for instance, http://www.dstrout.net/html/mac.htm - press the button and the displayed MAC changes every time. If you need help with the part of your code that uses this function, post another question.

Comment: This will generate `0` and `F` about half as frequently as any other individual number.

Answer (score 1):

try this [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uw7s2/)

all i did was to fix the display part :

```
function genMAC(){
var colours = new Array("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","A","B","C","D","E","F");
// Make variable to hold 6 character HEX array
var partA = new Array(1);
var partB = new Array(1);
var partC = new Array(1);
var partD = new Array(1);
var partE = new Array(1);
var partF = new Array(1);
var mac_address="";
for (i=0;i<2;i++){

    // Loop for partA
    partA[i]=colours[Math.round(Math.random()*14)];
}
    for (i=0;i<2;i++){
    // Loop through 6 times, randomising the letter added to the array
    partB[i]=colours[Math.round(Math.random()*14)];
}
    for (i=0;i<2;i++){
    // Loop through 6 times, randomising the letter added to the array
    partC[i]=colours[Math.round(Math.random()*14)];
}
    for (i=0;i<2;i++){
    // Loop through 6 times, randomising the letter added to the array
    partD[i]=colours[Math.round(Math.random()*14)];
}
    for (i=0;i<2;i++){
    // Loop through 6 times, randomising the letter added to the array
    partE[i]=colours[Math.round(Math.random()*14)];
}
    for (i=0;i<2;i++){
    // Loop through 6 times, randomising the letter added to the array
    partF[i]=colours[Math.round(Math.random()*14)];
}
// Returns like "a10bc5". It is likely that you may need to add a "#".
mac_address = partA[0]+ partA[1] + ":" + partB[0]+ partB[1] + ":" + partC[0]+ partC[1] + ":" + partD[0] + partD[1] + ":" + partE[0] + partE[1] + ":" + partF[0] + partF[1];
alert(mac_address);
}
```

if you just print/alert the array for example `partA` it would display like `3,2` and not `32` so you need to concatenate it each index it has.

Comment: May I ask why your hexadecimal alphabet has only 14 letters?

Comment: @Bergi, probably because I made a typo.

Comment: 6 times the same typo? (Maybe this type of programming hints at [a problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) with your code)

Comment: @Bergi i only copied the OPs code so basically it's not me. did you just -1 me?

Comment: Ah, I see - I had not expected bad code to be reposted without a comment (No, I didn't downvote).